# Corel AfterShot Pro photo editing software not starting after update from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: software-installation, upgrade

After an upgrade-in-place from 16.04.4 Gnome to 18.04 I discovered that Corel AfterShot Pro 2 (previously installed and running in 16.04) would no longer start.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I moved your question here to the main site, but pelase post your answer as an answer below. In the meantime, I am posting it as a community wiki. If you want to post it yourself (and get the reputation you deserve), please do so and flag mine for deletion.

Comment: Wait, when did Corel start supporting Linux?

Comment: @Seth For this exact software since at least Ubuntu 13.10 [as it seems](https://support.corel.com/hc/en-us/articles/215982568-AfterShot-Pro-1-installation-issue-on-Linux-Ubuntu-13-10-or-later) – didn't know that either.

Answer (score 1):

(Copied from the OP's [original post](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1030061/revisions))

---

The solution turned out to be a re-install of three dependencies. Apparently they get eliminated in the course of the upgrade.

See this page from Corel:

https://support.corel.com/hc/en-us/articles/235552727-AfterShot-Pro-Installation-fails-on-Ubuntu-16-10

> Problem: Installation of AfterShot Pro fails on Ubuntu 16.10, it is
>   recommended you follow the steps from the workaround below:
>
> Cause: Some of the libraries are not available in the new version of
>   the operating system.
>
> Workaround:
>
> Manually install libraries before installing AfterShot Pro
>
> 1. Reboot system to ensure all previous attempts to install the software are terminated.
> 2. Download and install the libraries, in the same order specified below:
>
> http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download
>   http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libgstreamer0.10-0/download
>   http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0/download
>
> 3. Proceed to the installation of AfterShot Pro
>
> AfterShot Pro will install successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I was asked to re-write my posting as a question and answer.

How do I get AfterShot Pro to run after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Answer:

The solution turned out to be a re-install of three dependencies. Apparently they get eliminated in the course of the upgrade.

See this page from Corel:

https://support.corel.com/hc/en-us/articles/235552727-AfterShot-Pro-Installation-fails-on-Ubuntu-16-10